# Create variables from content of a row in R

Tags: r

I have a hospital visit data that contain records for gender, age, main diagnosis, and hospital identifier.  I intend to create separate variables for these entries. The data has some pattern: most observations start with gender code (M or F) followed by age, then diagnosis and mostly the hospital identifier. But there are some exceptions. In some the gender id is coded 01 or 02 and in this case the gender identifier appears at the end. 
I looked into the archives and found some examples of grep but I was not successful to efficiently implement it to my data. For example the code

```
ndiag<-dat[grep("copd", dat[,1], fixed = TRUE),]
```

could extract each diagnoses individually, but not all at once.  How can I do this task?

Sample data that contain current situation (column 1) and what I intend to have is shown below:

```
diagnosis hospital  diag    age   gender
m3034CVDA   A   cvd 30-34   M
m3034cardvA A   cardv   30-34   M
f3034aceB   B   ace 30-34   F
m3034hfC    C   hf  30-34   M
m3034cereC  C   cere    30-34   M
m3034resPC  C   resp    30-34   M
3034copd_Z_01   Z   copd    30-34   M
3034copd_Z_01   Z   copd    30-34   M
fcereZ          Z   cere    NA      F
f3034respC  C   resp    30-34   F
3034copd_Z_02   Z   copd    30-34   F
```

Comment: Please include sample data that can be entered into R.  "dput" is a handy function for printing this from R.

Comment: Is there any data that does not either start or end with the gender code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be two key parts to this problem.

1. Dealing with the fact that strings are coded in two different
   ways
2. Splicing the string into the appropriate data columns

Note:  as for applying a function over several values at once, many of the functions can handle vectors already. For example `str_locate` and `substr`.

#### Part 1 - Cleaning the strings for m/f // 01/02 coding

```
# We will be using this library later for str_detect, str_replace, etc
library(stringr)

# first, make sure diagnosis is character (strings) and not factor (category)
diagnosis <- as.character(diagnosis)

# We will use a temporary vector, to preserve the original, but this is not a necessary step.
diagnosisTmp <- diagnosis

males <- str_locate(diagnosisTmp, "_01")
females <- str_locate(diagnosisTmp, "_02")

# NOTE: All of this will work fine as long as '_01'/'_02' appears *__only__* as gender code.
#  Therefore, we put in the next two lines to check for errors, make sure we didn't accidentally grab a "_01" from the middle of the string
#-------------------------
  if (any(str_length(diagnosisTmp) != males[,2], na.rm=T))  stop ("Error in coding for males")
  if (any(str_length(diagnosisTmp) != females[,2], na.rm=T))   stop ("Error in coding for females")
#------------------------

# remove all the '_01'/'_02'  (replacing with "")
diagnosisTmp <- str_replace(diagnosisTmp, "_01", "")
diagnosisTmp <- str_replace(diagnosisTmp, "_02", "")

# append to front of string appropriate m/f code 
diagnosisTmp[!is.na(males[,1])] <- paste0("m", diagnosisTmp[!is.na(males[,1])])
diagnosisTmp[!is.na(females[,1])] <- paste0("m", diagnosisTmp[!is.na(females[,1])])

# remove superfluous underscores
diagnosisTmp <- str_replace(diagnosisTmp, "_", "")

# display the original next to modified, for visual spot check
cbind(diagnosis, diagnosisTmp)
```

#### Part 2 - Splicing the string

```
# gender is the first char, hospital is the last. 
gender <- toupper(str_sub(diagnosisTmp, 1,1))    
hosp  <- str_sub(diagnosisTmp, -1,-1) 

# age, if present is char 2-5. A warning will be shown if values are missing. Age needs to be cleaned up
age   <- as.numeric(str_sub(diagnosisTmp, 2,5))    # as.numeric will convert none-numbers to NA
age[!is.na(age)]  <- paste(substr(age[!is.na(age)], 1, 2), substr(age[!is.na(age)], 3, 4), sep="-")

# diagnosis is variable length, so we have to find where to start
diagStart <- 2 + 4*(!is.na(age))
diag  <- str_sub(diagnosisTmp, diagStart, -2)

# Put it all together into a data frame
dat <- data.frame(diagnosis, hosp, diag, age, gender)
    ## OR WITHOUT ORIGINAL DIAGNOSIS STRING ##
dat <- data.frame(hosp, diag, age, gender)
```

Comment: I appreciate your spending so much of your valuable time to produce such a wonderful code. The script has successfully accomplished what I wanted and many thanks for that.